# how to `git diff` after `cherry pick`?

Tags: git

```
a - b - c - d   Master
     \
       e - f - g Feature
```

After `cherry-pick`,I cannot `diff` commit `f`.

```
git checkout master  
git cherry-pick f
git diff f
```

how to `git diff` after `cherry pick`?

Comment: In what way do you mean you "cannot" `diff`?  Does that mean the result of the `diff` is empty?  Or you get some sort of error messaging?

Comment: @AlexanderNied,diff is empty

Comment: Cherry-pick doesn't result in a diff. It creates a commit.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you mean by "f".

Perhaps it would help to have a clearer mental picture of what a cherry-pick does? It *copies* a commit, giving the copy a different hash. So there are now two commits with the same message, but with different hashes.

It also depends on your understanding of `git diff`. It may be that the phrase `git diff <some-commit>` needs some clarification; perhaps what you think it does is not what it really does.

---

First, you cannot *really* be saying `git diff f`, because `f` is not the name of a commit. So what are you really saying? Which hash are you specifying? Are you saying

```
git diff <the-original-f>
```

or are you saying

```
git diff <new-copy-of-f>
```

??

If you `git diff <the-original-f>`, you should see something in response.

But if you `git diff <new-copy-of-f>`, meaning the copy of `f` that is now on the end of `master`, naturally `git diff` will be empty, because you are comparing *two identical things*.

Why? Well, that brings me to my second point. The simple command `git diff <commit>` compares that commit to *the working tree*. Well, when you cherry pick, the working tree is updated to match the commit that you just cherry picked. So there is indeed no difference.

---

To demonstrate, I constructed your graph in real life. Here's the log:

```
* e09ed05 (HEAD -> feature) g
* 534df94 f
* d8b09e2 e
| * a01de45 (master) d
| * 9c56924 c
|/  
* 7f2fdd8 b
* e7a240b a
```

As you can see, `feature` branches off from `master` at `b`, just as in your first graph. Okay, now I will do what you did: I `checkout master` and `cherry-pick 534df94` (that is my "f"). And we get this:

```
* d9cc51a (HEAD -> master) f
* a01de45 d
* 9c56924 c
| * e09ed05 (feature) g
| * 534df94 f
| * d8b09e2 e
|/  
* 7f2fdd8 b
* e7a240b a
```

So now, as you see, there are two "f" commits: the original, `534df94` on `feature`, and the new copy, `d9cc51a` on the end of `master`.

Well, if I now `git diff 534df94` (the old "f"), there is a difference. But if I `git diff d9cc51a` (the new "f"), there is no difference and no response. And that is correct and expected. My working tree is identical to commit `d9cc51a`. This is exactly like saying `git diff master`, and I am *on* `master`; `master` is `HEAD` (as you can see from the log).

Comment: How to `diff` ` d9cc51a and a01de45`?

Comment: Uh, do you mean `git diff d9cc51a a01de45`?

Comment: `git diff d9cc51a a01de45` cannot show diff of `cherry-pick 534df94`.

Comment: What is the difference between a duck? (Old joke.) You cannot ask for `diff` of one thing. You are always comparing two things, even if you do not specify both of them. You are not clearly stating what two things you want to compare. I have answered the question as asked. I can do no more. The diff docs are here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff

Answer (score 0):

There is one way which we can see the changes done after cherry pick:

> $git log

after "git log" you will get commit id of your cherry pick, that you can use like below:

> $git show <commit-id>