# What is the reason git cherry-pick checks for conflicts

Tags: git

Why does cherry-pick check for conflicts between the cherry-picked commit from one branch and the commit where it will be put after on the other branch if the history will remain linear on that second branch? I'm just trying to understand the internals and rationale behind cherry-pick checking for conflicts despite the fact that all its purpose is to copy a commit from one location to another.

Comment: What do you mean by "check for conflicts"? A cherry-pick is by definition applying a diff, which may cause conflicts as a natural result (if the diff doesn't cleanly apply), that's not something that needs to be actively checked for. Do you expect a cherry-pick just straight-up replace all touched files with the version of the cherry-picked commit? Could you give an example where it caused a conflict and what you expected it to do instead?

Comment: A cherry pick _is_ a merge. So there can be merge conflicts. It is not some sort of arbitrary simple "copy"; that would be impossible. See my https://stackoverflow.com/a/65291733/341994 for a discussion of how cherry pick works.

Comment: yes, cherry-pick applies a diff but I'm trying to understand the reason for it. For example, suppose you have a repository and you want to cherry-pick a commit (A) from one branch and put it on top of another commit (B). Let's say the commit to be cherry-picked (A) conflicts with (B), then cherry-pick will not be able to copy commit (A) onto (B). But if I go to commit (B) and do the exact modifications that are in commit (A) then add and commit, then that would be possible. So it seems cherry-pick defeats its purpose.

Comment: @Doe: and how do you do "the exact modifications" automatically other than applying a diff? That's exactly what cherry-pick **does**. I fail to see the difference between what cherry-picking does and what you'd want it to do. Unless you just magically want it to resolve any conflicts on its own, which isn't feasible.

Comment: Using the same example from my last comment: let's say the commit I want to cherry-pick (A) has a file with lines: a, b, and c. Let's say the commit (B) has the same file but with lines: 1, 2, and 3. Using: `git cherry-pick A B` will result in a conflict error because cherry-pick uses diff. Yet, if I checkout to commit (B) then open the file and replace 1, 2, 3 with a, b, c then add then commit, the end result will look like I copied commit (A) on top of commit (B) and there will be no conflict of doing that. So my question is why cannot cherry-pick do the copy without checking for diff?

Comment: Now, this is a simple example that I used above which I can make it work manually but for larger repositories with multiple commits this manual process is daunting and cherry-pick is of no use if there were conflicts between the commit to be cherry-picked and the commit to be put on to.

Comment: But that's not what cherry-picking is! Cherry-picking is taking the difference between A to its predecessor (i.e. if X, the predecessor of A ,contained `a, b`then the diff is "add c") and applying that on top of B. If you just want to overwrite with the content of B then you don't need to cherry pick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way a cherry-pick works in Git is that it's a merge under the hood.  That merge applies the changes in a single commit from one place to another.

If that commit contains changes that also overlap with changes in the branch the commit is being cherry-picked to, then there is no simple way to resolve this, since the changes from the commit being cherry-picked cannot cleanly apply to the other branch, and so a conflict results.  This is the same thing that happens with any other merge conflict: both sides of the merge have changed in the same place, and there's no way to automatically pick which one should be adopted.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine this structure of repository:

```
master   feature
  |        |
  |        |
  m1       f1
  |        /
  |       /
  m2     f2
  |     /
  |    /
  common
```

Now we cherry pick `m1` to branch `feature`.

- `m1` can depend on some changes which has been made by `m2`. So since `m2` changed some lines `m1` changes then it is not clear what to do if same change is applyd on top of `feature` branch. So this is a conflict.
- also `f1` or `f2` can do changes for same lines as `m1`. Again it is not clear what to do in this case so user have to make a decition what should be done (resolve conflict).